# Question on exponential convergence and notation on derivative

Tags: analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, convergence-divergence

> Let $\;f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2\;$ and $\;g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb
>  R^2\;$ two maps which satisfy:
>
> $\;\vert D^\alpha (f-g)(x,y) \vert \le C e^{-k\vert x \vert}\;(*)$ for
>   $\;C,k\gt 0\;$ and $\;\alpha \in \mathbb N^2\;$ such that
>   $\;{\alpha}_1+{\alpha}_2\le 2\;$. ($\; \vert \cdot \vert\;$ represents
>    the Euclidean norm)

I'm having trouble understanding this $\;(*)\;$ kind of convergence. More specifically, the notation here confuses me a lot.

1. What does $\;D^{({\alpha}_1,{\alpha}_2)}\;$ stand for? I haven't seen this type of derivative before.
2. If I understand correctly the relation between $\;f,g\;$ , then from $\;(*)\;$ follows that the derivatives of $\;f\;$ converge to the derivatives of $\;g\;$ up to $\;\alpha\;$ order exponentially on the grounds that if $\;x \to \infty\;$, the right side of $\;(*)\;$ goes to zero. Am I right or did I miss something?

I would really appreciate if somebody could explain to me this notation and moreover confirm my thoughts/fix my mistake. Any help would be valuable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For 1, may be related to [higher order partial derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation#Definition_and_basic_properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\mathbb R^2$ $D^{\alpha}f=\frac{\partial^{|\alpha|} f}{\partial x^{\alpha_1} \; \partial y^{\alpha_2}}$. Basically $|\alpha|$ is the order and then you have to take the derivative with respect to the first variable $\alpha_1$ times and with respect to the second $\alpha_2$ times. In general if you have more dimensions you will also have $\alpha_3, \alpha_4,...,\alpha_n$, and those will be the times you have to derivate with respect to the variables $x_3,x_4,...,x_n$.
For the second part i think you got it right, the two derivatives (which can be each combination of $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ with $\alpha_1+\alpha_2 \le 2$ which are all the partial derivatives up to the second order) converge with at least "exponential speed" as $\|(x,y)\| \rightarrow +\infty $. I like to think that the function $h(x,y)=f-g$ is such that she and all its derivatives up to the second order go to $0$ when the norm of the argument goes to $\infty$, and they go at $0$ with exponential speed.

Comment: My first question was quite silly! Of course I've seen it before but not written like this. Thank you for your detailed explanation though!